# math.log in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program to print all the powers of ten before an inputted number. For example, if the input is 12345, the program should output 10, 100, 1000, 10000. Here is my program -

```
import math
limit = raw_input('Check until: ');
tenpowers=1
for i in range(1, int(limit)+1):
     if math.log(i, 10)==tenpowers:
         print 'tenpower! - ', i
         tenpowers=tenpowers+1
```

My program works correctly only if the input value is less than or equal to 100. Here's the output -

```
D:\py>python prog.py
Check until: 100
tenpower! -  10
tenpower! -  100

D:\py>python prog.py
Check until: 12345
tenpower! -  10
tenpower! -  100
```

Note the second time when I input 12345 and it still outputs only 10 and 100. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Just a tip by the way you don't need to end lines of code with `;` in python (its done automatically).

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice I even put that in. I work on Java at work and I'm new to Python. Didn't notice I did that. :-)

Comment: @Killrawr: It's _not_ done automatically. Python is not Javascript, which requires semicolons as statement terminators but magically adds them if they're missing; it doesn't require statement terminators at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math.log` uses floats and these almost always involve some rounding errors.

```
>>> math.log(1000, 10)
2.9999999999999996
```

If you need it to be exact you should change your algorithm to generate the powers of 10 (simply multiply the last power by 10) and continue as long as the new power is smaller than your input number.

```
>>> limit = 12345
>>> power = 10
>>> while power < limit:
...     print power
...     power = power * 10
... 
10
100
1000
10000
```

This is guaranteed to be exact as it does not involve any floating point numbers. (And is a lot faster, too)

Comment: Thanks! I put a debug statement - `print 'i - ', i, 'math.log(i,10) - ', math.log(i,10), ' tenpowers - ', tenpowers` before the 'if' condition and in this the value was always correct. I think the value of math.log(i,10) was rounded off when it was converted to a string. This was misleading.

Comment: @MediumOne: When you're debugging with floats, print out `repr(i)` instead of `i`. On some versions of Python, `print(2.9999999999999996)` will show `3`, while on others it will show `2.9999999999999996`. But `print(repr(2.9999999999999996))` will be `'2.9999999999999996'`.

Comment: Be careful when printing floating point numbers. They sometimes seam to be very precise put this happens due to the default precision when printing them. e.g. `0.1` really is not `0.1` due to the nature of floats. For checking float values you could use a format string like `'%.50f` % 0.1`

Comment: @abarnert `repr(0.1)` returns `'0.1'`. However there is no such thing as `0.1` in floating point numbers based on powers of `2`. `'%.50f' % 0.1` will show you the real value (rounded to 50 decimal places).

Comment: @bikeshedder: You're right, `repr(i)` is _still_ not always safe; it's just that it's safe more often than `str(i)`, and more consistent across Python versions/platforms. And, if even that isn't enough (and it sometimes isn't), you're right that `'%.50f'%(i,)` will get you all the digits on any platform where Python `float` is an IEEE double or smaller (which pretty much means any platform where Python is likely to run).

Answer (score 1):

[Floating-point math](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) strikes again! Look at the values returned by `math.log`:

```
>>> math.log(10000, 10)
4.0
>>> math.log(1000, 10)
2.9999999999999996
>>> math.log(100, 10)
2.0
>>> math.log(10, 10)
1.0
```

Comment: Yes, it is a floating point rounding error in my program. Thanks.